# Xcode: UIWebView pull-to-refresh animation not centered when website zoomed

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiwebview, pull-to-refresh

I have an iOS app created with Xcode and Swift. I'm using the following code for pull-to-refresh:

```
func pullToRefresh() {
        self.homewebview.reload()
}
func addRefreshControl() {
    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Please wait a moment…")
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FirstViewController.pullToRefresh), forControlEvents:.ValueChanged)
    self.homewebview.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}
```

It's working very well and the animation is shown, too. But, when the user has zoomed (in or out) the website and pulls to refresh the animation (spinning wheel, "Please wait a moment…" text) isn't show centered (horizontally) depending on which side of the zoomed website is actually shown.

Does anybody know how to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

1. Check if you are using `contentInsets`, if yes then set the layout constraints / layout anchors to `refreshControl.superView` with offsets.
2. Also set `tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl` instead of adding it as a subview

Answer (score 0):

If you have, for example, left-right inset `leftRightInset = CGFloat(value)`.

Then you can center refreshControl by using this code snippet:

```
refreshControl.bounds = CGRect(x: leftRightInset,
                               y: refreshControl.bounds.origin.y,
                               width: refreshControl.bounds.width,
                               height: refreshControl.bounds.height)
```